# How to customize TexMacs keymaps?

Tags: tex, texmacs

I already know to map key for snippets like below:

```
(kbd-map
  (:mode in-text?)
  ("w" (insert "Test message"))
```

What I'm looking for is how to map keys to move cursor position/paste/undo...
According to the help doc, this will need a coding language named Scheme, which I heard for the first time. So I'm looking for some samples to help me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You find most of the internal keybindings in files like `TeXmacs/progs/text/text-kbd.scm` and `TeXmacs/progs/math/math-kbd.scm`. They give you a pretty good overview of the possibilities. Note that there is a TeXmacs forum where you can get useful feedback from other users.